# Moving content from an old database to a new version of the database

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

If I want to add a column for example to an already existing database is there a standard way or method to upgrade the database and move the content from the old database to the new one and keep the new column empty? (I am using a local SQLiteDatabase android database)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps:

1. Update the Database Version:

Open your SQLiteOpenHelper class, where you manage your database creation and version management.
Increment the database version. This will trigger the `onUpgrade` method.

```
public class MyDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;  // Increment this when you modify the schema

    // ... rest of your code ...

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (oldVersion < 2) {
            // Perform the upgrade logic for version 2
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ADD COLUMN " + NEW_COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT;");
        }
        // ... other upgrade logic for other versions ...
    }
}
```

The `onUpgrade` method will be called when the database version changes, and you can use it to perform the necessary updates to your database schema.

2. Handle the New Column in Your Code:

Once you've added the new column, make sure your application code is prepared to handle this column (that is that as the new column does not have the NOT NULL constraint then it's value for all existing rows will be NULL)

- if the column has the NOT NULL constrain, then a default value would be required via the `DEFAULT` clause.

If it's a column that should be populated with specific values, you might need to add logic to your application to populate the new column appropriately, or you could utilise the `DEFAULT` clause to specify a suitable value.

Comment: You did not tell if the old data is conserved.